# How can I make a loop notification for two month in swift?

Tags: swift, loops, scheduling, uilocalnotification

I would like to send local and schedule notifications for two month, three times in a day.

I have set the first notification after user registration like this, though I don't know how should I continue it.

```
    dateComps.day = registrationDate.day
    dateComps.month = registrationDate.month
    dateComps.year = registrationDate.year
    dateComps.hour = 7
    dateComps.minute = 0

    let itemDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(dateComps)

    localNotif.fireDate = itemDate!.dateByAddingTimeInterval(24*60*60)
    localNotif.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()

    localNotif.alertBody = "Good Morning new user!"
    localNotif.alertAction = "View details"
    localNotif.alertTitle = "Good morning"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum amount of local notification an app can set in advance is 64, so actually for 3 notifications a day you can only set 21 days in advance.

The best you can do is every time the app opens call:
`UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications` and check the `fireDate` properties and schedule more notifications as needed.

Comment: Sorry i didn't notice your answer. could you explain more?

Comment: Of course. According to the limitations that apple imposes, an app may only register 64 local notifications in advance. that means that in your case, you may only set it 21 days in advance. The code I wrote, if you use it in your app will give you an array of the notifications that your app currently has scheduled. By looping over them and checking their `fireDate` property, you can find out what new alerts you need to set.